# IF @@trancount > 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION Causing blocking

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

We have a Java application / hibernate connecting to SQL Server. It looks like implicit transaction is on by default. I am not sure if this is from hibernate or JDBC Driver . However this implicit transactions are causing alot of blocking. when I checked I always find that the head of the blocking is

```
set implicit_transactions off IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
```

My question is
what can I perform from  the database side to avoid this problem?

[image]

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is the query i got from sp_whoisactive or sp_blitzfirst moreover implicit transaction warning  . I am not able to capture the whole transaction .

Comment: @ErikDarling I didn't find any information about implicit transactions in the JDBC docs

Comment: `con.setAutoCommit`

Answer (score -1):

I believe JDBC driver for SQLServer has IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON.  So you need to always commit your session/transaction with IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN.

I have had an issue where by a query from a NextGen MIRTH app has not been terminated with the COMMIT leaving the query locking and blocking other transactions for 20+ minutes until the spid was identified and killed in SQLServer.  At the moment i am assuming/speculating the older version of MIRTH in use  3.2.15 (off the top of my head) is the cause.  But why/Whats going wrong i aint sure?

The underlying blocking SQL was incrementing the ID on a channel table e.g. UPDATE D_MSQ149 SET ID = ID + 1.